# How to prohibit the removal of any rows in a specific mysql table?

Tags: mysql, security, delete-row, sql-delete

Is there a way to configure a mysql table so that writing and reading is possible but not deleting?

For example, a table that contains many logs that are legally important and that must never be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just grant the [INSERT and SELECT privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html) on the table in question (this prevents the possibility of a row being changed)

```
GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON mydb.mytable 
TO secureduser@localhost 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

From this you would go on to add wider permissions to the other tables in the database for this user.

Also, check out the [Archive Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html), which is custom designed for this kind of audit-trail application.

Answer (score 2):

[Revoke](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html) the delete [privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html) from all users for that table.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that UPDATE of a row is still possible though

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Archive storage engine. It only allows insertion, no updates or deletes (from anyone - even a privileged account)

Answer (score 0):

You could do as he says below or...
What you could do, is give users 'roles' in number form, then pass this number to a script which would remove the row... but if the passed number is below a certain 'minimum role expectation' then they are denied access to the script?

Comment: yes but human errors are still possible in my application code with this solution :) thx for answering btw